# How to use edittext.getText().toString()

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-edittext, adapter

I want to make it so that there is a `ListView` with a `Button` above it. The users clicks that button, and it opens a `dialog` with an `EditText` and an OK and Cancel button. When the user clicks OK, whatever text is entered into the `EditText` gets put into the `SQLiteDatabase`, which is reflected in the `ListView`.

I've already set up my `SQLiteDatabase` and have set an `adapter` for the List to show the `SQLiteDatabase`, but I need to figure out how to use the `edittext.getText().toString()` method to add to the `SQLiteDatabase`. **I will need a code example**.

If you need it, here's my main .java:

```
package com.gantt.shoppinglist;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ShoppingList extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper(this);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
        final SQLiteDatabase db = dataHelper.selectAll();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT oid as _id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY name", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = new String[]{"name"};
            int[] list = new int[]{android.R.id.list};
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, c, columnNames, list);
        }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
            final Dialog additem = new Dialog(ShoppingList.this);
            additem.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
            final EditText et = (EditText)additem.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            additem.setTitle("Type your item");
            additem.setCancelable(true);
            et.setHint("Type the name of an item...");

            Button button = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)  {
                    additem.dismiss();
                }
            });
            additem.show();

            Button ok = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    et.getText().toString();
                    additem.dismiss();
                    et.setText("");
                }
            });
       }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my DataHelper class:

```
package com.gantt.shoppinglist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataHelper {

       public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "items.db";
       public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
       public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
       public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

       private Context context;
       private SQLiteDatabase db;

       private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
       private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
          + TABLE_NAME + "(name) values (?)";

       public DataHelper(Context context) {
          this.context = context;
          OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
          this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
       }

       public long insert(String name) {
          this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
          return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
       }

       public void deleteAll() {
          this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
       }

       public SQLiteDatabase selectAll() {
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" }, 
            null, null, null, null, "name desc");
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0)); 
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return db;
       }

       public static String getDatabaseName() {
        return DATABASE_NAME;
    }

    private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          OpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, getDatabaseName(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
              db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT");

          }

          @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
             onCreate(db);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You pasted like several hundred lines of code up there.  That can't *possibly* all be relevent.  Which line(s) above do you need modified/expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the current methods you have, and assuming that you understand the code that you used for the database adapter, just do this:

```
String item = et.getText().toString();// these two lines are the
dataHelper.insert(item);              // only change you have to do
additem.dismiss();
et.setText("");
```

After doing this, you have to call the [`notifyDataSetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) method of your `SimpleCursorAdapter` object.

Comment: Hmm, whenever I do it, the `ListView` doesn't change. Maybe I need to tell the `ListView` or the `Cursor` or the DataHelper to be notified of a change?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that in my answer. Hold on.

Comment: Actually, I have to declare it final, but it says "The final local variable adapter cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment".

Comment: Declare it outside the onCreate method, and initialize it inside. And don't make it final.

Comment: LOL, not only did it not work, but now there is a small clickable area across the top of the `ListView`.

Comment: LOL, it has no errors. Here's the code: (I'm going to only show part of it)

Comment: `public class ShoppingList extends ListActivity {
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dataHelper.selectAll();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT oid as _id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY name", null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
             String[] columnNames = new String[]{"name"};
             int[] list = new int[]{android.R.id.list};
             adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlayout, c, columnNames, list);
            }
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: `Button ok = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 addItems();
                }

    private void addItems() {
     String item = et.getText().toString();
      dataHelper.insert(item); 
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    additem.dismiss();
                    et.setText("");
    }`

Comment: You know what, go to the SO chat and go to the android help room. I will be there for a while: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ok, now it only refreshes the data when I close my emulator and start up.

Comment: Call adapter.requery() torefresh the list after you insert

Answer (score 0):

A simple sample method for your DataHelper class:

```
public long createUser(String email, String password, String fullName) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("email", email);
    initialValues.put("password", password);
    initialValues.put("fullName", fullName);
    return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
}
```